# Unable to start Apache Tomcat server remotely (linux)

Tags: tomcat, ssh, remote-server

I have tried the following with little success:

1. run catalina.sh start command remotely

`$ ssh -t server-name sudo -H -u myuser sh /catalina/home/path/bin/catalina.sh start
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /catalina/home/path
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /catalina/home/path
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /catalina/home/path/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /catalina/home/path/../extraclasspathfiles:/catalina/home/path/bin/bootstrap.jar:/catalina/home/path/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
$ ssh -t server-name 'ps ax | grep java'
24322 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto java`

no luck

2. create remote startup script and run that remotely

here are the contents of remote.sh (this lives on the server)

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
export CATALINA_HOME="/catalina/home/path"
/catalina/home/path/bin/startup.sh
```

then we run the script remotely

```
$ ssh -t server-name sudo -H -u myuser sh /catalina/home/path/bin/remote.sh/bin/remote.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   Using CATALINA_BASE:   /catalina/home/path
Using CATALINA_HOME:   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /catalina/home/path
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /catalina/home/path/temp/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/../extraclasspathfiles:Using CLASSPATH:       /catalina/home/path/../extraclasspathfiles:/catalina/home/path/bin/bootstrap.jar:/catalina/home/path/bin/tomcat-juli.jar/bin/bootstrap.jar:Tomcat started./bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
$ ssh -t server-name 'ps ax | grep java'
24322 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

again, no luck

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting Tomcat on `server-name` and executing `ps` locally.

To see if Java is running on the remote machine you have to

```
ssh -t server-name 'ps ax | grep java'
```

Comment: okay, fair, that is how I wrote up the question. I was running the ps directly on the remote machine. I will fix the question

Comment: I wish it were that simple!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
ssh server-name sudo -H -u username sh /path/to/generated/bin/startup.sh
```

the `-t` was causing the ploblem.

```
-t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine,
             which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh
             has no local tty.
```